# Remove black box from text

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick},font=\sffamily]

\draw [very thick,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror,raise=4pt},yshift=0pt]
(1,-1) -- (5,-1) node [black,midway,yshift=-1cm] {\bfseries My text};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How to remove the black box around "my text"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm supposing you need the `draw` in `every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick}`. If you don't, you can remove it and the box will disappear.

Otherwise, use the `draw=none` option in the `node`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick},font=\sffamily]

\draw [very thick,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror,raise=4pt},yshift=0pt]
(1,-1) -- (5,-1) node [draw=none,black,midway,yshift=-1cm] {\bfseries My text};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

A small edit in the setting of `every node/.`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={},font=\sffamily]

\draw [very thick,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror,raise=4pt},yshift=0pt]
(1,-1) -- (5,-1) node [black,midway,yshift=-1cm] {\bfseries My text};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]